# Thread cron task in Java EE web app

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cron

I have a web app developed with Tapestry and deployed to Tomcat 7. I would like that this web app manages a "cron task" every day.

How can I create a dedicated and managed threaded task in my Java EE web app?

Comment: A lot of ways: timer beans, schedulers. What was your attempt?

Comment: Everyday I need to delete some data, in a Database and files on the system.